# Best practices for landscape only apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm a new iOS programming and I'm developing a simple iPhone game that needs to run in landscape only. I've ...

1. set supported orientations in the target settings
2. added the req. plist item (initial interface orientation)
3. overridden shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to return YES only for landscape modes

.. and the app "looks" correct, but there are a few odd things going on.

Issue 1 - I'm trying to manually position my views and not rely on autolayout. I've got a UIView in a NIB that I'm loading that needs to be positioned 150px from the right edge of the screen. I have to get the UIViewController's view's height (not width) to correctly position it - like it's not rotated to landscape at this point in the code.

Issue 2 - Implementing a UINavigationController to go from the title screen to the game interaction. When I'm pushing the interaction UIViewController to the stack, it slides in from the right like it's supposed to. When I go back to the title by popping the interaction, it slides UP to the title. It's seems like it's rotating back to portrait?

I think there is something very basic that I'm missing, but I can't find it in my app code. I've gone over the lists for a landscape app but they don't mention more than the list above.

Are there any other things/settings/methods to override that I should be on the look out for?

Comment: I've encountered the first issue, I found that in `-viewDidLoad:` views have not been rotated, but in `-viewWillAppear:` the view has been rotated to landscape and can be set up more the way you would expect. I'm no help on issue 2 I'm afraid

Comment: Did you set `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in your other viewControllers as well? Especially the ones displayed inside your UINavigationController.

Comment: @HolgerFrohloff that was it! fixed now! Thanks!

Comment: Great. Glad we solved it. I added it as an answer. Please accept it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in your other viewControllers as well. Especially the ones displayed inside your UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

Issue 2:

Don't use many UIViewController's. Use one view controller. Create one main UIViewController and for other UIViewController's just do:

```
[mainviewcontrl presentModalViewcontroller: child_viewcontrl animated: YES];
```

For delete a child view controller, use

```
[child_viewcontrl dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

Comment: Before I implemented the UINavigationController, I tried a using a plain UIViewController but with the code above, I didn't see my child VC's added to the screen. Couldn't figure it out, so I switched. And I like the transitions that the UINavigationController provides.